# Connection between Provability Logic (GL) and geometry?

Tags: lo.logic, modal-logic

In Provability Logic (aka GL) we have

- The Beth definability theorem and
- De Jong-Sambin Fixed Point Theorem

The former has a vague similarity to the implicit function theorem in that you can loosely read it as saying that injective (in some sense) functions of sentences define equations with unique well-defined solutions.

The latter is also about equations having solutions and is vaguely suggestive of the contraction mapping theorem. For example the function $P\mapsto\neg\Box P$ has a fixed point and it has one because the $P$ appears inside a $\Box$ operation, suggesting $\Box$ is a bit like a contraction.

Is there a topological or metric space interpretation of these theorems?

Comment: There seems to be an existing literature on topological semantics and provability logics. Thomas Icard has [slides on this](http://logic.berkeley.edu/colloquium/IcardSlides.pdf), and the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy has [a bit on the topic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-provability/#TopoSemaForProvLogi). I'm not sure how related this is to the specific topological/geometric intuitions you give here, but it might be of interest more broadly.

Comment: Maybe related, Maurice Herlihy uses Sperner's Lemma, along with other topological tools, to prove impossibility of distributed consensus in [The Topological Structure of Asynchronous Computability](http://cs.brown.edu/people/mph/HerlihyS99/p858-herlihy.pdf).